# How to access the custom div's inside the div class?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

Attached is a snip of the page which I am trying to access using BeautifulSoup and Python.

I want to the list of **data-clipid** and **data-cliphref**. But not able to move beyond with the code showed below.

Snip of the page I am trying to capture.

```
<div id="de-page-container" class="page-size mainclips" style="width: 600px; height: 912px;"> <div id="de-chunks-container" class="page-size" style="width: 600px; height: 912px;"><div id="left-bgThumbdiv" style="width: 600px; height: 912px; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px;"><img width="600" height="912" alt="" src="https://webpcache.epapr.in/index.php?in=https://cache.epapr.in/3627749/fbb9f591-b187-4ab1-a7ec-e1aa28dd8813/150x228-150x228/1x1.jpg" style="width: 600px; height: 912px;"></div><div id="left-chunk-0" loaded="true" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 600px; height: 912px;"><img alt="" width="600" height="912" src="https://webpcache.epapr.in/index.php?in=https://cache.epapr.in/3627749/fbb9f591-b187-4ab1-a7ec-e1aa28dd8813/600x912-600x912/1x1.jpg" style="width: 600px; height: 912px;"></div><div id="left-chunk-1" loaded="true" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 600px; height: 912px;"><img alt="" width="600" height="912" src="https://webpcache.epapr.in/index.php?in=https://cache.epapr.in/3627749/fbb9f591-b187-4ab1-a7ec-e1aa28dd8813/600x912-600x912/1x1.png" style="width: 600px; height: 912px;"></div></div> <div data-clipid="71078768" data-cliphref="#clip/71078768/7c177a5d-6e78-4a37-9d62-d5d25c845a19/591.1111111111111:653.3407987202194" class="clip-box clippageview" data-pgnum="1" data-bg-color="F9ECD1" style="width: 221.667px; height: 245.104px; top: 178.409px; left:
376.667px;"><a class="clip-enlarge-btn" href="javascript:"><i class="fa fa-search-plus"></i></a></div><div data-clipid="71078517" data-cliphref="#clip/71078517/0c97899f-f950-45e0-be0e-a08666bf657d/1509.7142857142856:1081.2063939821344" class="clip-box clippageview" data-pgnum="1" data-bg-color="F9ECD1" style="width: 566.143px; height: 405.619px; top: 185.659px; left: 15px;"><a class="clip-enlarge-btn" href="javascript:"><i class="fa fa-search-plus"></i></a></div><div data-clipid="71078544" data-cliphref="#clip/71078544/c3d19c1f-55a0-4f79-9098-40292c26d1a6/1508.5714285714284:800.0470145745182" class="clip-box clippageview" data-pgnum="1" data-bg-color="F9ECD1" style="width: 565.714px; height: 300.141px; top: 590.849px; left:
13.7143px;"><a class="clip-enlarge-btn" href="javascript:" style="display: none;"><i class="fa fa-search-plus"></i></a></div><div data-clipid="71080178" data-cliphref="#clip/71080178/26cac0c9-3146-4da6-bd3d-b316df54cce4/473.0647862991166:438.0681526814367" class="clip-box clippageview" data-pgnum="1" data-bg-color="F9ECD1" style="width: 177.399px; height: 164.343px; top: 0px; left:
292.302px;"><a class="clip-enlarge-btn" href="javascript:"><i class="fa fa-search-plus"></i></a></div><div data-clipid="71081916" data-cliphref="#clip/71081916/02b9a0b9-db4f-4f9f-b326-bfbe6f4bd43a/515.5555555555555:537.7839227560991" class="clip-box clippageview" data-pgnum="1" data-bg-color="F9ECD1" style="width: 193.333px; height: 201.752px; top: 585.247px; left: 0px;"><a class="clip-enlarge-btn" href="javascript:"><i class="fa fa-search-plus"></i></a></div><div data-clipid="71078445" data-cliphref="#clip/71078445/f6660e4c-3cc1-45be-aafa-f2785ed4aa84/540.5714285714286:181.7249647390691" class="clip-box clippageview" data-pgnum="1" data-bg-color="F9ECD1" style="width: 202.714px; height: 68.1749px; top: 522.674px; left:
381.429px;"><a class="clip-enlarge-btn" href="javascript:" style="display: none;"><i class="fa fa-search-plus"></i></a></div><div data-clipid="71078699" data-cliphref="#clip/71078699/966eb17a-42af-4150-94c2-a70417cf5379/524.4444444444446:968.8906619806102" class="clip-box clippageview" data-pgnum="1" data-bg-color="F9ECD1" style="width: 196.667px; height: 363.483px; top: 160.066px; left:
381.667px;"><a class="clip-enlarge-btn" href="javascript:" style="display: none;"><i class="fa fa-search-plus"></i></a></div><div data-clipid="71077661" data-cliphref="#clip/71077661/926b361f-e3fb-4416-9538-4cddc9ceb140/693.3333333333334:1155.5687596412042" class="clip-box clippageview" data-pgnum="1" data-bg-color="F9ECD1" style="width: 260px; height: 433.517px; top: 186.746px; left:
18.3333px;"><a class="clip-enlarge-btn" href="javascript:"><i class="fa fa-search-plus"></i></a></div><div data-clipid="71078702" data-cliphref="#clip/71078702/00da564e-09ca-4f9a-bc05-5c1324baf02c/174.85714285714292:420.5961448048894" class="clip-box clippageview" data-pgnum="1" data-bg-color="F9ECD1" style="width: 65.5714px; height: 157.788px; top: 523.103px; left:
514.714px;"><a class="clip-enlarge-btn" href="javascript:"><i class="fa fa-search-plus"></i></a></div><div data-clipid="71079005" data-cliphref="#clip/71079005/9a648159-fc7d-49c7-9e10-9ad77bc923c8/669.5181491178782:583.1289817703962" class="clip-box clippageview" data-pgnum="1" data-bg-color="F9ECD1" style="width: 251.069px; height: 218.763px; top: 683.687px; left:
335.678px;"><a class="clip-enlarge-btn" href="javascript:" style="display: none;"><i class="fa fa-search-plus"></i></a></div><div data-clipid="71078286" data-cliphref="#clip/71078286/1fd21cd7-3dd5-4285-9703-602466dafb79/306.7961165048545:1060.1947205621789" class="clip-box clippageview" data-pgnum="1" data-bg-color="F9ECD1" style="width: 115.049px; height: 397.737px; top: 180.657px; left:
262.136px;"><a class="clip-enlarge-btn" href="javascript:"><i class="fa fa-search-plus"></i></a></div><div data-clipid="71078440" data-cliphref="#clip/71078440/5dfc6239-fddf-4d12-95ca-4b2a4a6c47a9/457.1428571428571:284.58815232722156" class="clip-box clippageview" data-pgnum="1" data-bg-color="F9ECD1" style="width: 171.429px; height: 106.764px; top: 786.798px; left: 18px;"><a class="clip-enlarge-btn" href="javascript:"><i class="fa fa-search-plus"></i></a></div><div data-clipid="71078317" data-cliphref="#clip/71078317/7705ad7d-3e91-47fa-b16f-6e56df0264a8/493.2038834951457:283.4952915788977" class="clip-box clippageview" data-pgnum="1" data-bg-color="F9ECD1" style="width: 184.951px; height: 106.354px; top: 585.678px; left:
190.777px;"><a class="clip-enlarge-btn" href="javascript:"><i class="fa fa-search-plus"></i></a></div><div data-clipid="71078435" data-cliphref="#clip/71078435/a81e2610-8e80-474e-a4c2-b44320d98191/355.4285714285715:526.8881053126469" class="clip-box clippageview" data-pgnum="1" data-bg-color="F9ECD1" style="width: 133.286px; height: 197.664px; top: 691.611px; left:
201.857px;"><a class="clip-enlarge-btn" href="javascript:"><i class="fa fa-search-plus"></i></a></div><div data-clipid="71078423" data-cliphref="#clip/71078423/ab44afff-bc28-4a5e-8e06-389f1cb1f970/963.4285714285713:1099.4931828866947" class="clip-box clippageview" data-pgnum="1" data-bg-color="F9ECD1" style="width: 361.286px; height: 412.48px; top: 179.656px; left: 15px;"><a class="clip-enlarge-btn" href="javascript:" style="display: none;"><i class="fa fa-search-plus"></i></a></div><div data-clipid="71077781" data-cliphref="#clip/71077781/53e247ac-301a-4443-9b34-5afd0872a2ea/650.806547894674:564.8865053936621" class="clip-box clippageview" data-pgnum="1" data-bg-color="F9ECD1" style="width: 244.052px; height: 211.92px; top: 688.291px; left:
334.073px;"><a class="clip-enlarge-btn" href="javascript:" style="display: none;"><i class="fa fa-search-plus"></i></a></div></div>
```

Below is the code which I am using to extract and I have been fairly unsuccessful.

```
def getHTMLdocument(url):

# request for HTML document of given url
response = requests.get(url)

# response will be provided in JSON format
return response.text

url_to_scrape = "https://epaper.dishadaily.com"

# create document
html_document = getHTMLdocument(url_to_scrape)

# create soap object
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_document, 'html.parser')
linklist=[]


# find all the anchor tags with "href"
# attribute starting with "https://"
for link in soup.find_all('a',attrs={'href': re.compile("^https://")}):
    # display the actual urls
#   print(link.get('href'))
    linklist.append(link.get('href'))   

print('----------')
#print(linklist)
print(len(linklist))
substring = "latest?s="
for i in range(len(linklist)):
#   print(i)
    url_to_scrape1 = linklist[i]
    if url_to_scrape1.find(substring) != -1:
        print(url_to_scrape1)
        html_document1 = getHTMLdocument(url_to_scrape1)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html_document1, 'html.parser')
        for each_div in soup.find_all("div", attrs={"class":'clip-box clippageview'}):
#           for each_div2 in soup.find_all('div', {'id':True}):
            print(each_div)
```

Comment: What does "fairly unsuccessful" mean?  What works, what doesn't?

Comment: I am not able to capture anything beyond the page-size mainclips class. so what should I do to capture the divs inside them.

Comment: What is `getHTMLdocument`?  If you can get the outer div, then you should be able to get the inner divs.

Comment: that is what I have not been able to. I gave multiple combinations of IDs of div's and classes but always returns none.

Comment: What I meant was, are you using `requests` or Selenium?  It looks like that page is mostly built by Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

You can search for the divs with `class=clip-box clippageview`.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''
<div id="de-page-container" class="page-size mainclips" style="width: 600px; height: 912px;"> <div id="de-chunks-container" class="page-size" style="width: 600px; height: 912px;"><div id="left-bgThumbdiv" style="width: 600px; height: 912px; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px;"><img width="600" height="912" alt="" src="https://webpcache.epapr.in/index.php?in=https://cache.epapr.in/3627749/fbb9f591-b187-4ab1-a7ec-e1aa28dd8813/150x228-150x228/1x1.jpg" style="width: 600px; height: 912px;"></div><div id="left-chunk-0" loaded="true" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 600px; height: 912px;"><img alt="" width="600" height="912" src="https://webpcache.epapr.in/index.php?in=https://cache.epapr.in/3627749/fbb9f591-b187-4ab1-a7ec-e1aa28dd8813/600x912-600x912/1x1.jpg" style="width: 600px; height: 912px;"></div><div id="left-chunk-1" loaded="true" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 600px; height: 912px;"><img alt="" width="600" height="912" src="https://webpcache.epapr.in/index.php?in=https://cache.epapr.in/3627749/fbb9f591-b187-4ab1-a7ec-e1aa28dd8813/600x912-600x912/1x1.png" style="width: 600px; height: 912px;"></div></div> <div data-clipid="71078768" data-cliphref="#clip/71078768/7c177a5d-6e78-4a37-9d62-d5d25c845a19/591.1111111111111:653.3407987202194" class="clip-box clippageview" data-pgnum="1" data-bg-color="F9ECD1" style="width: 221.667px; height: 245.104px; top: 178.409px; left:
376.667px;"><a class="clip-enlarge-btn" href="javascript:"><i class="fa fa-search-plus"></i></a></div><div data-clipid="71078517" data-cliphref="#clip/71078517/0c97899f-f950-45e0-be0e-a08666bf657d/1509.7142857142856:1081.2063939821344" class="clip-box clippageview" data-pgnum="1" data-bg-color="F9ECD1" style="width: 566.143px; height: 405.619px; top: 185.659px; left: 15px;"><a class="clip-enlarge-btn" href="javascript:"><i class="fa fa-search-plus"></i></a></div><div data-clipid="71078544" data-cliphref="#clip/71078544/c3d19c1f-55a0-4f79-9098-40292c26d1a6/1508.5714285714284:800.0470145745182" class="clip-box clippageview" data-pgnum="1" data-bg-color="F9ECD1" style="width: 565.714px; height: 300.141px; top: 590.849px; left:
13.7143px;"><a class="clip-enlarge-btn" href="javascript:" style="display: none;"><i class="fa fa-search-plus"></i></a></div><div data-clipid="71080178" data-cliphref="#clip/71080178/26cac0c9-3146-4da6-bd3d-b316df54cce4/473.0647862991166:438.0681526814367" class="clip-box clippageview" data-pgnum="1" data-bg-color="F9ECD1" style="width: 177.399px; height: 164.343px; top: 0px; left:
292.302px;"><a class="clip-enlarge-btn" href="javascript:"><i class="fa fa-search-plus"></i></a></div><div data-clipid="71081916" data-cliphref="#clip/71081916/02b9a0b9-db4f-4f9f-b326-bfbe6f4bd43a/515.5555555555555:537.7839227560991" class="clip-box clippageview" data-pgnum="1" data-bg-color="F9ECD1" style="width: 193.333px; height: 201.752px; top: 585.247px; left: 0px;"><a class="clip-enlarge-btn" href="javascript:"><i class="fa fa-search-plus"></i></a></div><div data-clipid="71078445" data-cliphref="#clip/71078445/f6660e4c-3cc1-45be-aafa-f2785ed4aa84/540.5714285714286:181.7249647390691" class="clip-box clippageview" data-pgnum="1" data-bg-color="F9ECD1" style="width: 202.714px; height: 68.1749px; top: 522.674px; left:
381.429px;"><a class="clip-enlarge-btn" href="javascript:" style="display: none;"><i class="fa fa-search-plus"></i></a></div><div data-clipid="71078699" data-cliphref="#clip/71078699/966eb17a-42af-4150-94c2-a70417cf5379/524.4444444444446:968.8906619806102" class="clip-box clippageview" data-pgnum="1" data-bg-color="F9ECD1" style="width: 196.667px; height: 363.483px; top: 160.066px; left:
381.667px;"><a class="clip-enlarge-btn" href="javascript:" style="display: none;"><i class="fa fa-search-plus"></i></a></div><div data-clipid="71077661" data-cliphref="#clip/71077661/926b361f-e3fb-4416-9538-4cddc9ceb140/693.3333333333334:1155.5687596412042" class="clip-box clippageview" data-pgnum="1" data-bg-color="F9ECD1" style="width: 260px; height: 433.517px; top: 186.746px; left:
18.3333px;"><a class="clip-enlarge-btn" href="javascript:"><i class="fa fa-search-plus"></i></a></div><div data-clipid="71078702" data-cliphref="#clip/71078702/00da564e-09ca-4f9a-bc05-5c1324baf02c/174.85714285714292:420.5961448048894" class="clip-box clippageview" data-pgnum="1" data-bg-color="F9ECD1" style="width: 65.5714px; height: 157.788px; top: 523.103px; left:
514.714px;"><a class="clip-enlarge-btn" href="javascript:"><i class="fa fa-search-plus"></i></a></div><div data-clipid="71079005" data-cliphref="#clip/71079005/9a648159-fc7d-49c7-9e10-9ad77bc923c8/669.5181491178782:583.1289817703962" class="clip-box clippageview" data-pgnum="1" data-bg-color="F9ECD1" style="width: 251.069px; height: 218.763px; top: 683.687px; left:
335.678px;"><a class="clip-enlarge-btn" href="javascript:" style="display: none;"><i class="fa fa-search-plus"></i></a></div><div data-clipid="71078286" data-cliphref="#clip/71078286/1fd21cd7-3dd5-4285-9703-602466dafb79/306.7961165048545:1060.1947205621789" class="clip-box clippageview" data-pgnum="1" data-bg-color="F9ECD1" style="width: 115.049px; height: 397.737px; top: 180.657px; left:
262.136px;"><a class="clip-enlarge-btn" href="javascript:"><i class="fa fa-search-plus"></i></a></div><div data-clipid="71078440" data-cliphref="#clip/71078440/5dfc6239-fddf-4d12-95ca-4b2a4a6c47a9/457.1428571428571:284.58815232722156" class="clip-box clippageview" data-pgnum="1" data-bg-color="F9ECD1" style="width: 171.429px; height: 106.764px; top: 786.798px; left: 18px;"><a class="clip-enlarge-btn" href="javascript:"><i class="fa fa-search-plus"></i></a></div><div data-clipid="71078317" data-cliphref="#clip/71078317/7705ad7d-3e91-47fa-b16f-6e56df0264a8/493.2038834951457:283.4952915788977" class="clip-box clippageview" data-pgnum="1" data-bg-color="F9ECD1" style="width: 184.951px; height: 106.354px; top: 585.678px; left:
190.777px;"><a class="clip-enlarge-btn" href="javascript:"><i class="fa fa-search-plus"></i></a></div><div data-clipid="71078435" data-cliphref="#clip/71078435/a81e2610-8e80-474e-a4c2-b44320d98191/355.4285714285715:526.8881053126469" class="clip-box clippageview" data-pgnum="1" data-bg-color="F9ECD1" style="width: 133.286px; height: 197.664px; top: 691.611px; left:
201.857px;"><a class="clip-enlarge-btn" href="javascript:"><i class="fa fa-search-plus"></i></a></div><div data-clipid="71078423" data-cliphref="#clip/71078423/ab44afff-bc28-4a5e-8e06-389f1cb1f970/963.4285714285713:1099.4931828866947" class="clip-box clippageview" data-pgnum="1" data-bg-color="F9ECD1" style="width: 361.286px; height: 412.48px; top: 179.656px; left: 15px;"><a class="clip-enlarge-btn" href="javascript:" style="display: none;"><i class="fa fa-search-plus"></i></a></div><div data-clipid="71077781" data-cliphref="#clip/71077781/53e247ac-301a-4443-9b34-5afd0872a2ea/650.806547894674:564.8865053936621" class="clip-box clippageview" data-pgnum="1" data-bg-color="F9ECD1" style="width: 244.052px; height: 211.92px; top: 688.291px; left:
334.073px;"><a class="clip-enlarge-btn" href="javascript:" style="display: none;"><i class="fa fa-search-plus"></i></a></div></div>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

links = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "clip-box clippageview"})
```

Then you can subset the clipids and cliphrefs from these elements.

```
clipids, cliphrefs = [link["data-clipid"] for link in links], [link["data-cliphref"] for link in links]

print(clipids)
#['71078768', '71078517', '71078544', '71080178', '71081916', '71078445', '71078699', '71077661', '71078702', '71079005', '71078286', '71078440', '71078317', '71078435', '71078423', '71077781']

print(cliphrefs)
#['#clip/71078768/7c177a5d-6e78-4a37-9d62-d5d25c845a19/591.1111111111111:653.3407987202194', '#clip/71078517/0c97899f-f950-45e0-be0e-a08666bf657d/1509.7142857142856:1081.2063939821344', '#clip/71078544/c3d19c1f-55a0-4f79-9098-40292c26d1a6/1508.5714285714284:800.0470145745182', '#clip/71080178/26cac0c9-3146-4da6-bd3d-b316df54cce4/473.0647862991166:438.0681526814367', '#clip/71081916/02b9a0b9-db4f-4f9f-b326-bfbe6f4bd43a/515.5555555555555:537.7839227560991', '#clip/71078445/f6660e4c-3cc1-45be-aafa-f2785ed4aa84/540.5714285714286:181.7249647390691', '#clip/71078699/966eb17a-42af-4150-94c2-a70417cf5379/524.4444444444446:968.8906619806102', '#clip/71077661/926b361f-e3fb-4416-9538-4cddc9ceb140/693.3333333333334:1155.5687596412042', '#clip/71078702/00da564e-09ca-4f9a-bc05-5c1324baf02c/174.85714285714292:420.5961448048894', '#clip/71079005/9a648159-fc7d-49c7-9e10-9ad77bc923c8/669.5181491178782:583.1289817703962', '#clip/71078286/1fd21cd7-3dd5-4285-9703-602466dafb79/306.7961165048545:1060.1947205621789', '#clip/71078440/5dfc6239-fddf-4d12-95ca-4b2a4a6c47a9/457.1428571428571:284.58815232722156', '#clip/71078317/7705ad7d-3e91-47fa-b16f-6e56df0264a8/493.2038834951457:283.4952915788977', '#clip/71078435/a81e2610-8e80-474e-a4c2-b44320d98191/355.4285714285715:526.8881053126469', '#clip/71078423/ab44afff-bc28-4a5e-8e06-389f1cb1f970/963.4285714285713:1099.4931828866947', '#clip/71077781/53e247ac-301a-4443-9b34-5afd0872a2ea/650.806547894674:564.8865053936621']
```

Comment: This is working when the html is taken as an input. Is there a way to extract that part of the html from the entire html tree of the page and then use it as an input to the code you provide?

Comment: Considering the information you are looking for is not in the page source, but generated dynamically using javascript, you will not be able to extract the information using requests. You should use Selenium here.